# Blocking calls(wait, com calls) in STA thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, com+, sta, waitformultipleobjects

I have a windows service which creates 10+ threads which:

- do their job and then enter WaitForMultipleObjects state until they are resumed again ..
- each thread creates TDCOMConnection component calls method on its AppServer and then
  closes the connection

The service works fine, however I have seen memory leaks problems.

I am just curious if that issue can be related with message pumping.

I have always thought that message pumping in STA threads should only be applied
when I use com marshalling (in situation that i have a proxy between two threads)

But today I read somewhere that in case blocking calls I should take care of messages.
Is that true?

However My application still function correctly, doesn't block itself ...

Maybe I should use: CoWaitForMultipleHandles instead of: WaitForMultipleObjects?

Any thoughts on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that using WaitForMultipleObjects rather than CoWaitForMultipleHandles will result in memory leaks.  Which function you use is really up to you but should have no impact on whether or not you leak.

To solve this I think you need to get some detailed diagnostics about your leaks.

Comment: Yes I will have to dig into, however i am just curious if I should process messages in my STA threads ..

Comment: @Paul Hard to tell without knowing more about it. Do you see problems the way you currently do it?

Comment: actually no ... except of the small one .. memory leaking. It seems to my that threads calling com+ methods are the reason of my problems, because if i remove the lines which call these methods to see if the Task objects are allocated/.deallocated correctly then everything works ok and the memory is not growing up ...